# Как проверить множество на наличие элемента?

Tags: java, массивы, linked-list, compare

У меня имеется `LinkedList<String> varSet` и `operationSet`. В `varSet` я храню список стринговых переменных: `x^2,x,cos(x)` . В `operationSet` --> `+ -*/`. На вход метода я получаю массив стрингов типа: `(+,-,-,+,+,x,tan,x,cos)`. Такой массив - это представление функции `( ( ( x + tan(x) ) - ( x + cos(x) ) ) + ( ( x + ctg(x) ) - ( x - cos(x) ) ) )` в виде бинарного дерева. Я должен сделать мутацию массива посредством замены рандомного элемента на новый. И если на месте того рандомного индекса раньше был элемент из множества `varSet`, то вставляю новый (рандомный) элемент из `varSet`. Аналогично с `operationSet`. После вызова метода `mutateTree` каждый раз получаю неизмененный входящий стринг.

Как это можно исправить?

```
String[] binaryGeneTree = new String[15]; 

private LinkedList<String> createXSet() {
    LinkedList<String> myXSet = new LinkedList<>();
    myXSet.add("x");
    myXSet.add("cos(x)");
    myXSet.add("sin(x)");
    myXSet.add("tan(x)");
    myXSet.add("x^0.5");
    myXSet.add("x^0.2");
    myXSet.add("x^-3");
    myXSet.add("x^2");
    myXSet.add("x^3");
    xSet = myXSet;

    return xSet;
}

/**
 * Method create set of operations
 * */
private LinkedList<String> createOperandSet() {
    LinkedList<String> myOperandSet = new LinkedList<>();
    myOperandSet.add("+");
    myOperandSet.add("-");
    myOperandSet.add("*");
    myOperandSet.add("/");
    operationSet = myOperandSet;
    return operationSet;
}


public String[] mutateTree(String[] strings) {
    binaryGeneTree = strings;
    LinkedList<String> varSet = createXSet();
    LinkedList<String> operationSet = createOperandSet();

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * strings.length);
    if (xSet.contains(binaryGeneTree[x])) {
        binaryGeneTree[x] = varSet.get(new Random().nextInt(varSet.size()));
    } else if (operationSet.contains(binaryGeneTree[x])) {
        binaryGeneTree[x] = operationSet.get(new Random().nextInt(operationSet.size()));
    }

    return binaryGeneTree;
}
```

Comment: А что вы подаете в качестве вхрдных данных?  Увас если элемент найден не был, то массив будет неизменным

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Например, в качестве инпута: `String[] equation={"+","-","-","cos(x)","sin(x)","x^2","x",null,null,...};`  В таком случае я еще дополнительно вызываю метод :   `public int getSizeofList(){
        int a=0;
        for(int i=0;i<binaryGeneTree.length;i++){
            if(binaryGeneTree[i]!=null){
                a++;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }`  И потом это `a` передаю в `mutateTree()` как int `x = (int) (Math.random() * getSizeofList());`

Answer (score 0):

Проверка на наличие - `boolean containsX = varSet.contains("x");`

Comment: У меня в коде это есть: `if (xSet.contains(binaryGeneTree[x])) {
            binaryGeneTree[x] = varSet.get(new Random().nextInt(varSet.size()));
        }`